# ReSharper formatting: disable extended indentation for multi-line statements

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm not sure if my title is entire accurate, however, I would like to disable the feature in ReSharper formatting where it indents deep (?) upon formatting. The following image describes the behaviour (red = before format, green = after format)

:
[image: ReSharper formatting]

As you can see the indentation for all the statements after the first line are indented very far.

```
var shouldSendMails = requester.Email != model.Email
    || requester.PhoneNumber != model.PhoneNumber
    || requester.Address != model.Address
    || requester.PostalCode != model.PostalCode
    || requester.City != model.City
    || requester.MedicalInformation != model.MedicalHistory;
```

Turns into

```
var shouldSendMails = requester.Email != model.Email
                    || requester.PhoneNumber != model.PhoneNumber
                    || requester.Address != model.Address
                    || requester.PostalCode != model.PostalCode
                    || requester.City != model.City
                    || requester.MedicalInformation != model.MedicalHistory;
```

I would like to disable this behaviour. So what I want is when I format the code, it does format the code, but without the 4 extra tabs before putting the new line of code there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DavidG that is the end of the statement, the picture shows a Git diff

Comment: Yeah, figured that out in the end :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after posting the question I found the feature.

It is named "Align Multiline Constructs" and can be found here:

ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other -> Align Multiline Constructs.

For me, the option "Expression" was checked/enabled. Disabling this option fixed the problem for me.

Before disabling "Expression" option:

```
destination = source1
                  ? source2
                  : source3;
```

After disabling "Expression" option:

```
destination = source1
    ? source2
    : source3;
```

Answer (score 0):

That also fixes indent in LINQ extension methods.

Since I use EF a lot, it was incredibly annoying...

```
var invoice = this.context.Invoices
                  .Include(i => i.InvoiceLines)
                  .Where(i => ........................................)
```

Becomes like that after disabling:

```
var invoice = this.context.Invoices
    .Include(i => i.InvoiceLines)
    .Where(i => ........................................)
```

[image]